# NET 4.5 WCF Features: HTTPS

Tags: web-services, wcf, iis, https, .net-4.5

One of new features:

```
 New HTTPS protocol mapping to make it easier to expose an 
 endpoint over HTTPS with Internet Information Services (IIS).
```

Does it mean that I do not need add https enpoint to the service anymore?

Now I use NET 3.5. Installer checks IIS settings and adds this endpoint to the web.config if customer wants to work via https, i.e.

http://myhost.com/mysvc.svc
https://myhost.com/mysvc.svc

If I understand right, in NET 4.5 it is enough one address

http://myhost.com/mysvc.svc

for **http** and **https**.

Is it correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the following sites; "In WCF 4.5, if IIS is enabled for SSL and if the service does not have any explicit endpoint defined for the specific binding, then WCF can be hosted on IIS with default HTTPs enabled i.e. ‘basicHttpsBinding’."

Refer to the following links for detailed information and examples:
http://www.dotnetcurry.com/showarticle.aspx?ID=866
http://johnlnelson.com/tag/wcf-4-5/